# How to get Site Template Back?

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have saved a site as tempalte (i.e. MyMarketing.stp) and added to sharepoint server using stsadm addtemplate command and after few days lost MyMarketing.stp file. Now it is available for creating top level sites as well. I want to get this site template back as MyMarketing.stp file. Is it possible to extract it from the server as MyMarketing.stp file?

Thanks and in advance!

Regards,

Asher

Answer (score 0):

Create an new site based on the template, then use `http://SITEURL/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx` to save the site in it's own site template gallery. you can now download the .stp file from that gallery.

Alternatively you could use SharePoint designer to export the site as a template.